# Binomial Coefficient Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I'd like to ask whether there exists some simple criterion to determine whether the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{m}$ is divisible by a prime $p$. For the case $p=2$, the criterion is $\binom{n}{m} \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 2) \iff n \ \& \ m \neq m$, where $\&$ is the bitwise-and operation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem